# Regarding the submission of a form with JS

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I am currently attempting to fix a hyperlink on a page that is meant to act as a form submit button.

The button is supposed to do two things:

1. Check if a validation function, called empty(); , returns true
2. If so, submit the form

The button code is:

```
<a role="button" class="button_primary" id="WC_AccountDisplay_links_2" onclick="submitLogonForm();">
 <div class="left_border"></div>
 <div class="button_text">Sign In</div>
 <div class="right_border"></div>
</a>
```

The onclick code is:

```
<script>

function submitLogonForm() {

 return empty();

  if(empty()) {

    document.Logon.action="security.php";
    document.Logon.submit();

  }

}

</script>
```

And the form code is:

```
<form method="post" name="Logon" action="security.php" id="Logon">
```

The empty() check runs fine, but the form does not submit, and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you put `return` statement before the form submit code. Those lines are unreachable and will never be executed since your function returns and terminates midway.

Comment: I tried without the return statement, but the form still does not submit.

Comment: Never mind - I just added a "else { return true; }" condition to my empty() function and it works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function submitLogonForm() {
  if(notempty()) {

    document.forms[0].submit();

  }
}
function notempty() {
   // do validations here 
   //if any field is empty - return false 
   //else 
   return true;
}


<form action="security.php">
<a role="button" class="button_primary" id="WC_AccountDisplay_links_2" onclick="submitLogonForm();">
 submit
</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work for me - the empty() function doesn't just check for empty fields - it also displays custom modal dialog popups with specific alerts if a field is empty. I can't just discard it.

Comment: You can check all that in the and return true or false in that function. I will edit to show you.

Comment: I still don't understand why my code does not submit the form - if the empty() function returns true, the submission code should execute ( it executes just fine, if I don't set up the execution of the empty() function first ).

Comment: Never mind - I just added a "else { return true; }" condition to my empty() function and it works like a charm now!